# about save data in the storage wp 8.1

Tags: c#, visual-studio, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

I created this code in same 3 page p1+p2+p3:

```
public partial class P1 : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    IsolatedStorageSettings UserDatas = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
    int point;
    int level;

    public P1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += P1_Loaded;
    }

    private void P1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (UserDatas.Contains("Points") && UserDatas.Contains("Levels"))
        {

            PBlock.Text = "Point: " + UserDatas["Points"];
            LBlock.Text = "Levels: " + UserDatas["Levels"];
        }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        point = point + 5;
        level = level + 1;
        UserDatas["Points"] = point + 5;
        UserDatas["Levels"] = level + 1;

        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/P2.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
}
```

}

when click button and go to p2 [point = 5, level = 1]
and directly click button and go to p3 output [point = 10 , level = 2]
But when I go to page 4 outputs remain such as P3, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output of page-4 is exactly what is supposed to be.

In fact, all page that are navigated afterward will have `point = 10` and `level = 2` according to your code/logic.

The reason is simple, when the constructor is called both `point` and `level` are set to `0`. In `Button_Click` function you have increased their value by 5 and 1 respectively. So the updated values are 5 and 1. Now you have put the `point + 5` and `level + 1` in  `UserDatas`. So `point` will always be 10 and `level` be 2.

**Note:** If you are trying to increase point by 5 and level by 1 for every page navigation just replace your `Button_Clink` function with following snippet:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    UserDatas["Points"] = UserDatas["Points"] + 5;
    UserDatas["Levels"] = UserDatas["Levels"] + 1;

    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/P2.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Comment: UserDatas["Points"] = UserDatas["Points"] + 5; with +5 is not working, he is field because "Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'int'  "

Comment: can you be more specific what's the exact problem? Is it data type mismatch? In case of type mismatch you can cast it by `int.parse(UserDatas["Points"].ToString())`

If otherwise please be specific to the exact error.